# Perform replace on all columns of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume the following `#temptable`

```
ID    location    price    quantity    comment
----------------------------------------------
1     new york      15        10       nice
```

In reality, the table has many more columns. I want to quickly make a select and perform a replace operation on each column:

```
select
    replace(ID, char(10), ' ')
  , replace(location, char(10), ' ')
  , replace(price, char(10), ' ')
  , replace(quantity, char(10), ' ')
  , replace(comment, char(10), ' ')
from
    #temptable
;
```

To do this on 1000 columns, for multiple tables, is cumbersome. So I am trying to do this dynamically:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @column varchar(max)

declare cur cursor for select * 
                       from tempdb.sys.columns 
                       where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temptable')

fetch next from cur into @column
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin   
    set @sql = @sql + 'replace(' + @column + ', char(10), ""),'
    fetch next from cur;
end

@sql = 'select ' + @sql + ' from #temptable'

select @sql 

--sp_execute(@sql)
```

This is the best I can come up with, but obviously it does not work. Can you help me getting this code to work?

Comment: Are all the columns text?  Some of them look numeric.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the comment. In the same loop, I will cast them all as text first.

Comment: "obviously it does not work" - Why doesn't it work? Error messages?

Comment: With this code snippet, there are lots of syntax errors. So are you getting syntax errors or it is executing and you are getting functional errors? can you elaborate the issue you are facing?

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit (sorry, I am typing between two separate networks and cannot copy-paste). The error I get is "cursor is not open"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note open cursor, close cursor and deallocate cursor. Also you want to select the name column for your cursor.  Good article on the topic - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'Select '
declare @column varchar(8000)

declare cur cursor for select name 
                       from tempdb.sys.columns 
                       where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temptable')
Open cur

fetch next from cur into @column;
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin   
    set @sql = @sql + 'replace(' + @column + ', char(10), '' ''),'
    --select @sql
    fetch next from cur into @column;
end
close cur
deallocate cur

Set @sql = Substring(@sql,1,Len(@sql)-1) + ' from #temptable'

--select @sql

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a cursor to build the statement to execute you can do it this way:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + CHAR(10) + ',','') 
               + 'REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ', CHAR(10), '' '')' 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temptable')

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @cols  + ' FROM #temptable'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Given your sample temp table this would build and execute the following statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE([ID], CHAR(10), ' ')
,REPLACE([location], CHAR(10), ' ')
,REPLACE([price], CHAR(10), ' ')
,REPLACE([quantity], CHAR(10), ' ')
,REPLACE([comment], CHAR(10), ' ') FROM #temptable
```

You should probably qualify the query from sys.columns and add a filter for `system_type_id` to only operate on columns with a character data type (like 167 (varchar) or 175 (char)), if it's not meaningful for you to run the replace on binary data too.